# slicing pandas columns individually between first and last valid index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, slice, missing-data

Say I have a dataframe `df` with P columns where there can be missing data at different rows, e.g. first row data available for column 1 but for for 2, and potentially vice-versa for other rows. I want to select, for each column separately, the column data between first and last valid index (which, again, can differ across columns), and check if there are NaNs left. Then, I would like to exclude those columns that meet such condition.

My code works this way:

```
for i in df.columns:
    df_i = df[i]
    trimemd_i = df_i.loc[df_i.first_valid_index():df_i.last_valid_index()]
    if np.any(trimmed_i.isnull()):
        continue
    else:
        good_data.append(i)
df = df.loc[:, good_data]
```

The problem is that the loop is slow if I have many columns. Is there a more efficient way to do it, maybe avoiding loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming such an input, in which you want to remove "C":

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  2.0  2.0  NaN
3  3.0  3.0  3.0
4  NaN  4.0  NaN
```

You can remove the columns with inner NaNs using [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) a double [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) to identify the inner NaNs, then [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to select the columns that have no inner NaNs:

```
tmp = df.notna()

out = df.loc[:, tmp.eq(tmp.cummax() & tmp[::-1].cummax()).all()]
```

Output:

```
     A    B
0  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  1.0
2  2.0  2.0
3  3.0  3.0
4  NaN  4.0
```

Intermediates:

```
# getting NaNs
# tmp
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True   True   True
2   True   True  False
3   True   True   True
4  False   True  False

# removing inner NaNs
# tmp.cummax() & tmp[::-1].cummax()
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True   True   True
2   True   True   True
3   True   True   True
4  False   True  False

# identifying inner NaNs (as False)
# tmp.eq(tmp.cummax() & tmp[::-1].cummax())
      A     B      C
0  True  True   True
1  True  True   True
2  True  True  False
3  True  True   True
4  True  True   True

# columns to keep (no inner NaNs)
# tmp.eq(tmp.cummax() & tmp[::-1].cummax()).all()
A     True
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: spectacular solution! cut the time to almost a third, and very smart idea behind it. Works wonders!

Comment: @user9875321__ out of curiosity, can you time the same logic in numpy? `tmp = df.notna().to_numpy() ; df.loc[:, (tmp == (np.maximum.accumulate(tmp)&np.maximum.accumulate(tmp[::-1])[::-1])).all(axis=0)]`

Comment: seems slightly faster: first solution is 145 ms, second 130 ms